# Identity Server 4 Auto Login After Registration Not Working

Tags: identityserver4

I want the user to be auto logged in after registration within an `ASP.NET` Core `MVC` app after email verification (via a `OTAC`). Ben Foster's blog post is great, but it's Identity Server 3, so lots has changed in v4.

http://benfoster.io/blog/identity-server-post-registration-sign-in

I've got all the bits working except for the last step, i.e. the actual logging in part.

As you can see, I'm overriding `ProcessInteractionAsync` within a custom `AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator` but something isn't quite right because the wrong user (weirdly, a previously registered user?) is logged in when redirected back to client app, even though the code below picks up the correct user from the `OTAC`.

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

```
public override async Task<InteractionResponse> ProcessInteractionAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request, ConsentResponse consent = null)
{
    var acrValues = request.GetAcrValues().ToList();
    var otac = acrValues.SingleOrDefault();

    if (otac != null && request.ClientId == configuration.GetSection("ScafellWebClientId").Value)
    {
        var crypto = new Crypto();
        var hashed = crypto.Hash(otac);
        var user = FindUserByOtac(hashed);

        if (user.ValidateOtac(hashed))
        {
            Logger.LogDebug("OTAC valid");

            user.RevokeOtac();

            await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);

            return new InteractionResponse
            {
                IsLogin = false,
                IsConsent = false
            };
        }
    }

    return await base.ProcessInteractionAsync(request, consent);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have it. This seems to work.

```
        public override async Task<InteractionResponse> ProcessInteractionAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request,
        ConsentResponse consent = null)
    {
        var acrValues = request.GetAcrValues().ToList();
        var otac = acrValues.SingleOrDefault();

        if (otac != null && request.ClientId == configuration.GetSection("ScafellWebClientId").Value)
        {
            var crypto = new Crypto();
            var hashed = crypto.Hash(otac);
            var user = FindUserByOtac(hashed);

            if (user.ValidateOtac(hashed))
            {
                user.RevokeOtac();

                var claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.IdentityProvider, request.Subject.GetIdentityProvider())
                };

                var svr = new IdentityServerUser(user.Id)
                {
                    AuthenticationTime = clock.UtcNow.DateTime,
                    AdditionalClaims = claims
                };

                var claimsPrincipal = svr.CreatePrincipal();
                request.Subject = claimsPrincipal;

                await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);

                return new InteractionResponse
                {
                    IsLogin = false,
                    IsConsent = false,
                };
            }
        }

        return await base.ProcessInteractionAsync(request, consent);
    }
```

Thanks for your time.