# Session Id (sid) is not assigned during automatic login via IdentityServer4, what gives?

Tags: identityserver4

**Questions**

First question, what determines if an `sid` claim is emitted from identityserver?

Second question, do I even need an `sid`?  I currently have it included because it was in the sample..

**Backstory**

I have one website that uses IdentityServer4 for authentication and one website that doesn't.  I've cobbled together a solution that allows a user to log into the non-identityserver4 site and click a link that uses one-time-access codes to automatically log into the identityserver4 site.  Everything appears to work except the `sid` claim isn't passed along from identityserver to the site secured by identityserver when transiting from the non-identityserver site.  If I log directly into the identityserver4 secured site the `sid` **is** included in the claims.  Code is adapted from examples of automatically logging in after registration and/or impersonation work flows.

Here is the code:

**One time code login process in identityserver4**

```
public class CustomAuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator : AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator
{
...
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/51466043/391994
    public override async Task<InteractionResponse> ProcessInteractionAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request,
    ConsentResponse consent = null)
    {
        string oneTimeAccessToken = request.GetAcrValues().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Split(':')[0] == "otac");

        string clientId = request.ClientId;

        //handle auto login handoff 
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oneTimeAccessToken))
        {
            //https://benfoster.io/blog/identity-server-post-registration-sign-in/
            oneTimeAccessToken = oneTimeAccessToken.Split(':')[1];
            OneTimeCodeContract details = await GetOTACFromDatabase(oneTimeAccessToken);

            if (details.IsValid)
            {
                UserFormContract user = await GetPersonUserFromDatabase(details.PersonId);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    string subjectId = await GetClientSubjectIdAsync(clientId, user.AdUsername);

                    var iduser = new IdentityServerUser(subjectId)
                    {
                        DisplayName = user.AdUsername,
                        AuthenticationTime = DateTime.Now,
                        IdentityProvider = "local",
                    };

                    request.Subject = iduser.CreatePrincipal();

                    //revoke token
                    bool? success = await InvalidateTokenInDatabase(oneTimeAccessToken);

                    if (success.HasValue && !success.Value)
                    {
                        Log.Debug($"Revoke failed for {oneTimeAccessToken} it should expire at {details.ExpirationDate}");
                    }

                    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/56237859/391994
                    //sign them in
                    await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme, request.Subject, null);

                    return new InteractionResponse
                    {
                        IsLogin = false,
                        IsConsent = false,
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        return await base.ProcessInteractionAsync(request, consent);
    }
}
```

**Normal Login flow when logging directly into identityserver4 secured site (from sample)**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handle postback from username/password login
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model)
    {
        Log.Information($"login request from: {Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()}");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // validate username/password against in-memory store
            if (await _userRepository.ValidateCredentialsAsync(model.Username, model.Password))
            {
                AuthenticationProperties props = null;
                // only set explicit expiration here if persistent. 
                // otherwise we reply upon expiration configured in cookie middleware.
                if (AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin && model.RememberLogin)
                {
                    props = new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        IsPersistent = true,
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
                    };
                };

                var clientId = await _account.GetClientIdAsync(model.ReturnUrl);

                // issue authentication cookie with subject ID and username
                var user = await _userRepository.FindByUsernameAsync(model.Username, clientId);

                var iduser = new IdentityServerUser(user.SubjectId)
                {
                    DisplayName = user.UserName
                };

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(iduser, props);

                // make sure the returnUrl is still valid, and if yes - redirect back to authorize endpoint
                if (_interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }

                return Redirect("~/");
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", AccountOptions.InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage);
        }

        // something went wrong, show form with error
        var vm = await _account.BuildLoginViewModelAsync(model);
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

**AuthorizationCodeReceived in identityserver4 secured site**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                {
                    // use the code to get the access and refresh token
                    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(
                        tokenEndpoint,
                        electionClientId,
                        electionClientSecret);

                    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                        n.Code, n.RedirectUri);

                    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
                    }

                    // use the access token to retrieve claims from userinfo
                    var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(
                    new Uri(userInfoEndpoint).ToString());

                    var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

                    Claim subject = userInfoResponse.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "sub").FirstOrDefault();

                    // create new identity
                    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);

                    id.AddClaims(GetRoles(subject.Value, tokenClient, apiResourceScope, apiBasePath));

                    var transformedClaims = StartupHelper.TransformClaims(userInfoResponse.Claims);

                    id.AddClaims(transformedClaims);

                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn).ToLocalTime().ToString()));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
    THIS FAILS ->   id.AddClaim(new Claim("sid", n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("sid").Value));

                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                        new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType, "name", "role"),
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                },
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Questions again if you don't want to scroll back up**

First question, what determines if an `sid` claim is emitted from identityserver?

Second question, do I even need an `sid`?  I currently have it included because it was in the sample..